# how to change xticks font size in a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i have the following code :

```
ax=df_pivoted.plot(figsize=(30,15),linewidth=5)
plt.xticks( rotation=45)
plt.tick_params(labelsize = 20)
plt.xlabel('transaction_date', fontsize=20)
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('daily sale graph test_id=505 ',fontdict={'fontsize':30})
legend = ax.legend(loc=0, ncol=1, bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0, 1,1),fancybox=True,shadow=False,title='variations',prop={'size':30})


plt.setp(legend.get_title(),fontsize='30')
xposition = c12_days
for xc in xposition:
    ax.axvline(x=xc, color='g', linestyle='--')

plt.show()
```

above code produce following graph where i have dates in x axis but the problem is that as you can see days have very small size but JUL and AUG are bigger i have tried different font sizes for xticks and tick_params but have not seen any major change. how can i change the code to have day numbers as big as JUL and AUG?

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try to use [`tick_params` function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html?highlight=tick_params#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) like here:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=24)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=16)
```

You may specify axis like 'x' or 'y' instead of 'both'.

Comment: was about to suggest something like `for tick in ax.xaxis.get_minor_ticks(): tick.label.set_fontsize(14)` But your solution is ofc the way to go in newer versions of MPL