# How do I increase ticks fontsize using matplotlib without passing labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to increase the ticks fontsize on a plot (both x and y axes) without passing labels as an input argument to `ax.set_yticklabels()`

For example, say I have the y-data below (x-data doesn't matter for this example, so you could set `x=np.arange(len(y))`)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
y = np.array([ 5840.5,  3579.5,  2578. ,   965.5,   748. ,   485. ])
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot(np.arange(len(y)), y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now what I would like to do is increase the fontsize of the y-ticks, but I want to leave the labels the same and in the same location as matplotlib has created them. So I tried

```
ax.set_yticklabels(fontsize=20)
>>> TypeError: set_yticklabels() missing 1 required positional argument: 'labels'
```

which of course doesn't work. But if I pass some labels as an argument

```
y = np.array([ 5840.5,  3579.5,  2578. ,   965.5,   748. ,   485. ])
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot(np.arange(len(y)), y)
ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(0,y.max(),1000), fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

the fontsize does increase, but the labels and scale aren't the same as the original plot. I need to be able to change the fontsize for any array `y`, not just this example given above, so passing a specific label isn't possible.

Ideally what I want looks like this: the same labels and scale as in the first plot, but the y-ticks fontsize is larger. I want to produce this plot without passing labels each time I plot, because my x and y variables are dynamic. Is there a way to do this?
[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390393/matplotlib-make-tick-labels-font-size-smaller). There are several other links which address this problem. Here is another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710545/how-to-change-xticks-font-size-in-a-matplotlib-plot)

Comment: See especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11386056/4124317) for the purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the ytick rc param which will change the ytick fontsize for each subsequent plot using:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rc('ytick', labelsize=20)
```

Alternatively if you want to do this for only one figure, you can loop through each label and change the fontsize:

```
for label in ax.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_fontsize(20)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plt.yticks()` as follows:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot(np.arange(len(y)), y)
plt.yticks(fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```